# Simple SAX or DOM parser in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, dom, sax

I am not able to find a simple implementation of the SAX or DOM parser .... if anybody can give me somem pointers on it or share some links it will be gr8 , as all I can see is some third party parsers in C++.

Comment: What do you want to parse? HTML, XML or what?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/). From it's homepage:

> TinyXML is a simple, small, C++ XML parser that can be easily integrating into other programs.

There is a newer version available from the author called [TinyXML-2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

part of boost. small and fast.
http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Also the [boost::property_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/property_tree.html). It is not what you would call small but has plenty of functionality.